# remove trailing zeros in awk not working. syntax error

Tags: shell, regular-expression, awk

```
regex = "\\.*0+$";
subst = "";
system("echo "id "| awk '{sub(\\.*0+$," subst"); print}'");
```

It is giving the following error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(\.*0+$,); print}
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ backslash not last character on line
```

I tried this one as well

```
system("echo "id "| awk '{sub("regex"," subst"); print}'");
```

and This is also no worky.

```
 str="echo " id " | awk '{sub(" regex  "," subst "); print;}'" ; str | getline check;
```

This is giving me same exception

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {sub(\.*0+$, ); print}
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ backslash not last character on line
```

But, on the command line, this function is working fine.

```
echo 444000 | awk '{sub("\\.*0+$",""); print}' -> 444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you put your regex inside `/ /` (didn't know you could do away with those at all), and make sure the substitution ends up quoted:

```
system("echo "id "| awk '{sub(/\\.*0+$/,\""subst"\"); print}'");
```

Or:

```
system("echo "id "| awk '{sub(/"regex"/,\""subst"\"); print}'");
```

But I'm not sure why you are not simply doing:

```
sub(/\.*0+$/,"",id);
print id;
```

to avoid that whole `system` call.

Comment: yes, that's what I was looking at as a matter of fact, I didn't know sub would accept a third argument. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well we both learned something on this one :)